# Analyzing Relationship across Categorical Variables

Tags: regression, correlation, categorical-data, dataset, intraclass-correlation

I am working on some corpus data related to semantic tagging and syntactic constructions. Finally, I prepared a table of results yet I am unable to go on further due to lack of statistical knowledge.

I have the table as follows;

[image: Double Object Constructions]

What I am trying to do is to assess relationship/correlation across columns, the ratio of if Agent = inanimate/nonpronoun then the ratio of recipient = animate/pronoun and theme = inanimate/nonpronoun etc.

Can you guide me to the right way to explore the relationship among variables? I would like to create a correlation matrix table when Agent X then Recipient Y and Theme Z (strength among them?)

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need a loglinear model to assess relationships between all three of your variables at the same time. Essentially, what you have here are counts in a crosstab: You have N1 cases of inanimate/nonpronoun subjects with animate/pronoun recipients and inanimate/nonpronoun themes, N2 cases of inanimate/nonpronoun subjects with animate/pronoun recipients and animate/pronoun themes, and so on for all possible combinations of your variables and their levels. What you are interested in is actually whether the frequency of observations across different categories is independent. Independence basically means that knowing what the value of one variable (say, agent) is will not help you predict the value of another variable (say, theme). This can be intuitively seen if you imagine an extreme case, say, animate agents only ever occur with animate recipients and animate themes. In this case, there is no independence, as knowing that your agent is animate immediately lets you know what value the other two variables will assume.

You would run your loglinear model with all three of your variables with their highest order interactions (agent*theme, agent*recipient, recipient*theme, agent*recipient*theme). The results will tell you if, for instance, the odds of having an animate theme is higher for animate agents than for inanimate ones.

Comment: wow, awesome answer! Indeed, I have just applied Loglinear model yet results are confusing. For instance,

Recipient ✻ Theme ✻ Agent:
(animate/pronoun – animate/nonpronoun) ✻ (animate/pronoun –
animate/nonpronoun) ✻ (animate/pronoun – animate/nonpronoun) 26.303 825915 3.18e -5 1.000
(inanimate/nonpronoun – animate/nonpronoun) ✻ (animate/pronoun –
animate/nonpronoun) ✻ (animate/pronoun – animate/nonpronoun) 2.61e-10 882941 2.95e-16 1.000

I got for the first slot both animate/pronoun and inanimate/pronoun together. Why not individually?

Comment: Can you clarify your software output a bit? Can you maybe upload a screenshot of the output window?